# Js How to got the sum of numbers from a string?

Tags: javascript, string, sum

I'm new to coding and have been given this question;

Create a function that takes a string with a jumble of letters and numbers. It should add together all the numbers that appear in the string and return the total.

```
   E.g. 'foo5bar6cat1' => 12
   'foo99cat' => 18
```

Tip: For this one, it might be useful to know that the value `NaN` in JavaScript behaves oddly. For example, if you do `typeof NaN` it tells you it's a `"number"`. Odd, eh?

The code that I have written is this;

```
function sumDigitsFromString(str) {
let nums = []
let sum = 0

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
if (typeOf (arr[i]) === "number") {
 nums.push(str[i])
    }
}
 for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
sum.push(nums[i] + sum)
   }
return sum
}
```

The test that my code is being run against is this;

```
describe("sumDigitsFromString", () => {
   it("picks out a digit from a string and returns", () => {
expect(sumDigitsFromString("foo5foo")).to.equal(5);
   });
     it("sums multiple digits from a string", () => {
expect(sumDigitsFromString("5foo5foo")).to.equal(10);
    });
it("returns a seum of several digits in a string", () => {
         expect(sumDigitsFromString("hello1world5this3is2a2string")).to.equal(13).;
   });
});
```

Dose anyone have any suggestion of how to fix my code?

Comment: You are using `arr` in `typeOf (arr[i]) === "number"` instead of `str`.

Comment: You could use Regex: `let sum = 0; 'foo5bar6cat1'.replace(/\d/g, n => sum += +n); return sum;`

Comment: `'foo5bar6cat1'.split(/[^0-9]/).filter(Boolean).map(Number).reduce((x,y)=>x+y,0)`

Comment: @blex very nice!

Comment: `typeof (str[i]) === "number"` will always be `false` because `str[i]` returns a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function numberAdd(str){
 var strArr = str.split(""), strTemp=0;
 for(i=0;i<strArr.length;i++){
  if(!isNaN(strArr[i])){
   strTemp+=parseInt(strArr[i]);
  }
 }
 return strTemp;
}

var str = 'foo5bar6cat1';
console.log(numberAdd(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method won't work because of so many reasons, Try to change your method as following and it should do the trick,

```
function sumDigitsFromString(str) {
    var sum = 0;
    var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i]
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost on the right track.

```
if (typeOf (arr[i]) === "number") {
```

I think you meant to use `str[i]` instead of `arr[i]`. `arr` was not defined earlier.

```
if (typeof(str[i]) === "number") {
```

This will always be false. Every `str[i]` is a string. Correct is using:

```
if (!isNaN(Number(str[i]))) {
```

where if `str[i]` is not a number, `Number(str[i])` will return `NaN`.

```
nums.push(str[i])
```

You need to push numbers not strings. Use `Number(str[i])`.

```
sum.push(nums[i] + sum)
```

`sum` is of type Number. You can't push to a number. You need to add to that number. Use `sum += nums[i]` instead.

So the complete, working code will be:

```js
function sumDigitsFromString(str) {
  let nums = [];
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(str[i]))) {
      nums.push(Number(str[i]));
    }
  }
  console.log(nums);
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += nums[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

// Test it
console.log(sumDigitsFromString("foo5bar6cat1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution if you are solving for **numbers as the combination of a series within a string** (ie 'zz11yx33ab' -> 44) or ('020a010b030c11' -> 71).

```js
let string = '020a010b030c11';

function sumNumbers(string) {
  let pos = 1;
  let numArray = [];
  let numString = null;

  for (let num of string) {
    let isParsed = isNaN(parseInt(num));
    if (!numString && !isParsed && pos === string.length) {
      numArray.push(num);
    } else if (!numString && !isParsed && pos !== string.length) {
      numString = num;
    } else if (numString && !isParsed && pos === string.length) {
      numString += num;
      numArray.push(numString);
    } else if (numString && isParsed && pos === string.length) {
      numArray.push(numString);
    } else if (numString && !isParsed) {
      numString += num;
    } else if (numString && isParsed && pos !== string.length) {
      numArray.push(numString);
      numString = null;
    } else if (!numString && isParsed && pos === string.length) {
      numString += num;
      numArray.push(numString);
    }
    pos++;
  }
  console.log('numAray:', numArray);
  let result = null;

  for (let num of numArray) {
    let value = parseInt(num);
    result += value;
  }
  return result;
}

let finalNum = sumNumbers(string);
console.log(finalNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum =0;
for(char of string)
    isNaN(parseInt(char)) ? sum=sum+0:sum=sum+parseInt(char);
```

this should serve the purpose....ES6 syntax used.

Answer (score 0):

- `typeOf` is supposed to be `typeof`. You don't want this in your code though because it will give all the elements in the string array a string value.
- Use `parseInt()` to make all the elements in the array numbers and then weed out the ones who return `NaN` with `isNaN()`

  ```
  function sumDigitsFromString(str) {
      let nums = []
      let sum = 0

      for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
          if (!isNaN(parseInt(str[i]))) {
              sum += parseInt(str[i])
          }
      }
      return sum
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let test = 'naseef123hello66'

//declared an empty array
let nums = [];

//declared a sum variable  
let sum = 0;

//check whether it is number or alphabet 
for(i=0;i<test.length;i++){
 if (!isNaN((test[i]))) {
  nums.push(Number(test[i]));
 }
}

//itrating arr and find sum with basic arithmetic operation
for (k=0;k<nums.length;k++){
sum = sum + nums[k]
}

console.log("sum : "+sum)
```

```
let test = 'naseef123hello66'

//declared an empty array
let nums = [];

//declared a sum variable  
let sum = 0;

//check whether it is number or alphabet 
for(i=0;i<test.length;i++){
 if (!isNaN((test[i]))) {
  nums.push(Number(test[i]));
 }
}

//itrating arr and find sum with basic arithmetic operation
for (k=0;k<nums.length;k++){
sum = sum + nums[k]
}

console.log("sum : "+sum)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
 let str= "add123456with376765willgive887686";
    // expected output:123456+376765+887686 => 1387907
    
    const sumOfNumbers = (str) => {
        let sum = 0
        let temp = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        //check current item is Number or not
            if(Number(str[i])){   
                  temp = temp + str[i];
                 // reset temp string to empty if next item is not a number
                if(!Number(str[i+1])){ 
                    sum = sum + Number(temp)
                    temp = ''
                }
            }
        }
        return sum
    }
```

Comment: You should add explanation.